# Why does SonarLint allow a negative threshold for Cognitive complexity (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse, cognitive-complexity

In `Windows -> Preferences -> SonarLint -> Rules Configuration -> Java -> (search cognitive complexity)`, while selecting the rule for cognitive complexity, I was able to set a negative value for the threshold.

[image]

I was able to successfully apply the change, and sonar warnings were also generated:

[image]

**What is the purpose of allowing a negative threshold, or is this a bug?**

Comment: So the UI allows to enter a negative value, which [according to the documentation](https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/cognitive-complexity) and as you already found out yourself does not make sense. What prevents you [providing a patch](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-eclipse) for what you call a bug?

Comment: @howlger should bugs also be added under "Suggest new feature"?

Comment: Make a [pull request for your patch here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-eclipse/pulls).